# ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick with Laravel webpack & NPM

Tags: laravel, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I tried installing these packages but can't get neither to run / compile with npm run dev.
I tried for several hours serching and installing dependencies with no luck-
I did
brew install GraphicsMagick
npm install gm

my app.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

var fs = require('fs')
    , gm = require('gm');

new Vue({
    el: '#app'
    , data: {

    }
});
```

and the result:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/gm/node_modules/cross-spawn/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'spawn-sync' in '/Users/mauricebalde/code/v3/node_modules/gm/node_modules/cross-spawn'
 @ ./node_modules/gm/node_modules/cross-spawn/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/gm/lib/compare.js
 @ ./node_modules/gm/index.js
 @ ./resources/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss

ERROR in ./node_modules/gm/node_modules/cross-spawn/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/Users/mauricebalde/code/v3/node_modules/gm/node_modules/cross-spawn'
 @ ./node_modules/gm/node_modules/cross-spawn/index.js 3:9-33
 @ ./node_modules/gm/lib/compare.js
 @ ./node_modules/gm/index.js
 @ ./resources/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss

ERROR in ./node_modules/gm/lib/convenience/morph.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/mauricebalde/code/v3/node_modules/gm/lib/convenience'
 @ ./node_modules/gm/lib/convenience/morph.js 6:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/gm/lib/convenience.js
 @ ./node_modules/gm/index.js
 @ ./resources/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss

ERROR in ./node_modules/gm/node_modules/cross-spawn/lib/parse.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/mauricebalde/code/v3/node_modules/gm/node_modules/cross-spawn/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/gm/node_modules/cross-spawn/lib/parse.js 3:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/gm/node_modules/cross-spawn/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/gm/lib/compare.js
 @ ./node_modules/gm/index.js
 @ ./resources/js/app.js
```

Comment: This module requires that you have ImageMagick intalled on your machine. There are numerous ways to install them, whats's your OS? For instance, if you're on OS X you can use Homebrew: `brew install imagemagick`

Comment: I did that ofcourse, but still this errors occur.
im on OSX and I tried it on 2 different machines. Always the same result!?

Answer (score 0):

[everything installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EK5e9.png)
still this orruc keeps occurring